# How to solve and plot a cubic equation in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am pretty new with matlab, and right now I am a bit lost. I want to solve the following cubic equation and then plot both real and imaginary roots:

x^3-d*(x^2)+1 =0

Where l is a parameter between [-10 10] and x[-5 5].
Thank you

Comment: You are talking about a parameter l, but there is no l in the equation. Do you have the symbolic math toolbox available?

Answer (score 1):

Is it always going to be?

`y=x^3-d*(x^2)+1`?

If so, you can use the `roots` function

```
y = roots([1, -d, 0, 1]);
```

Where the vector is the equation's coefficients